# Conditional unstable rustc feature?

Tags: rust

I need to have removed line switching on the experimental rustc feature if the current rustc is stable. Is that possible something like that?

```rust
#![cfg_attr(rustversion::nightly, feature(type_name_of_val))]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the Rust forum I have found out that there are 2 ways to solve the problem:

- with help of a custom feature declared in `cargo` file
- with help of the environment variable `RUSTFLAGS`

#### How to enable `rustc` feature conditionally with a custom feature declared in `cargo` file?

1. Declare feature to `cargo` file. `rustc` unstable feature will be bound to the one declared in `cargo` file. For example:

```
[features]
nightly = []
default = [ "nightly" ]
```

I chose the name `nightly`, but it is arbitrary. Feature `default` describes which features are switched on by default.

2. Conditionally switch on `rustc` feature in the root file of your project:

```rust
#![ cfg_attr( feature = "nightly", feature( type_name_of_val ) ) ]
```

`feature = "nightly"` reffer `cargo` file feature declared earlier.
`feature( type_name_of_val )` - declaring of [this unstable `rustc` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name_of_val.html).
Note: `rustc` unstable features should be declared in the root file at the beginning for the whole executable. Otherwise, you will get: crate-level attribute should be in the root module.

3. Use unstable `rustc` feature conditionally:

```rust
#[ cfg( feature = "nightly" ) ]
println!( "{} is {}", i, std::any::type_name_of_val( &i ) );
```

`#[ cfg( feature = "nightly" ) ]` tells compiler to remove the associated line if custom feature `nightly` is disabled. In our case feature `nightly` is enabled by default in `cargo` file `default = [ "nightly" ]`.

#### How to enable `rustc` feature conditionally with environment variable `RUSTFLAGS`?

1. Conditionally switch on `rustc` feature in the root file of your project:

```rust
#![ cfg_attr( nightly, feature( type_name_of_val ) ) ]
```

`nightly` reffer [`--cfg` flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html)
`feature( type_name_of_val )` - declaring of [this unstable `rustc` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name_of_val.html).
Note: `rustc` unstable features should be declared in the root file at the beginning for the whole executable. Otherwise, you will get: crate-level attribute should be in the root module.

2. Use unstable `rustc` feature conditionally:

```rust
#[ cfg( nightly ) ]
println!( "{} is {}", i, std::any::type_name_of_val( &i ) );
```

`#[ cfg( nightly ) ]` tells compiler to remove the associated line if `rustc` does not get `cfg` `nightly`. We are going to pass it with the environment variable `RUSTFLAGS` in the next step.

3. Run your executable with the environment variable `RUSTFLAGS`

```sh
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg nightly" cargo run
```

The environment variable `RUSTFLAGS="--cfg nightly"` tells [cargo to pass arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustflags) `--cfg nightly` to the compiler.

#### Solutions

- [Custom feature declared in `cargo` file](https://github.com/Wandalen/RustPractice/tree/dc466f20058b37f23447eb15e83f625a3afa9264/all/rustc_feature_conditional/with_feature_single/main)
- [Custom feature declared in `cargo` file + several modules](https://github.com/Wandalen/RustPractice/tree/dc466f20058b37f23447eb15e83f625a3afa9264/all/rustc_feature_conditional/with_feature)
- [Environment variable `RUSTFLAGS`](https://github.com/Wandalen/RustPractice/tree/dc466f20058b37f23447eb15e83f625a3afa9264/all/rustc_feature_conditional/with_rustflag_single/main)
- [Environment variable `RUSTFLAGS` + several modules](https://github.com/Wandalen/RustPractice/tree/dc466f20058b37f23447eb15e83f625a3afa9264/all/rustc_feature_conditional/with_rustflag)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rustversion](https://lib.rs/crates/rustversion) crate.

```
[depedencies]
rustversion = "1"
```

```rust
#![rustversion::attr(nightly), feature(type_name_of_val))]
```

**Edit:** There is an [accepted RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2523-cfg-path-version.md) for `#[cfg(version(...))]`. It [used to include](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2523-cfg-path-version.md#cfgnightly) a `#[cfg(nightly)]` flag, but now it does not.

**Edit:** There are also the crates [rustc_version](https://lib.rs/crates/rustc_version) and [version_check](https://lib.rs/crates/version_check).

Comment: Thanks, but that neither work.